# Is the interior of the union of $n$ closed balls equal to the union of the interiors of the $n$ closed balls?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.
I am solving problem 1-22 on p.10 now.
If the following equality holds, I can solve the problem.

Let $B_1, \dots, B_n$ be closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Intuitively, I guess the following equality holds, but I cannot prove that.

Does the following equality hold?

$$\operatorname{Int}(B_1 \cup \dots \cup B_n) = \operatorname{Int}(B_1) \cup \dots \cup \operatorname{Int}(B_n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intuition is correct in one sens

this a counterexample take two intervals $[1,2]$and $[2,3]$
it's clear that the interior of the union is not equal to the union of the interior  even if your sets are closed

Comment: Bernstein, Thank you very much for the counterexample.

Comment: You are welcome, bro. I guess if  you  add the conditions two by two disjoint, this will work

Comment: Thank you very much for additional information.

Comment: @Bernstein Would non-overlapping suffice? Instead of disjoint

Comment: sorry, but what is the meaning of non-overlapping?

Comment: @Bernstein Only intersecting on boundaries

Comment: @Divide1918   Thank you for your explication, I  think this has the same meaning because by assumptions in the question the sets are closed

Comment: But if $m>1$ it looks true for $n \leq m$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof for the direction that seems to be correct. For a point P, if $P\in B_{Q_1}(\varepsilon_{Q_1}) \;\;\cup\;...\cup\;B_{Q_m}(\varepsilon_{Q_m})$, it also lies in at least one of the open balls, say $P\in B_{Q_j}(\varepsilon_{Q_j})$. Hence P lies in the interior of $\overline{B_{Q_1}(\varepsilon_{Q_1})}\;\cup \;...\cup \;\overline{B_{Q_m}(\varepsilon_{Q_m})}$, and we then have $$B_{Q_1}(\varepsilon_{Q_1}) \;\;\cup\;...\cup\;B_{Q_m}(\varepsilon_{Q_m})\subseteq int(\overline{B_{Q_1}(\varepsilon_{Q_1})}\;\cup \;...\cup \;\overline{B_{Q_m}(\varepsilon_{Q_m})})$$.

The other direction fails as demonstrated by counterexample in Bernstein's answer.